# Gnuplot - User - Error: "all points y value undefined!"

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my program. I am trying to plot data whose format looks fine to me. Gnuplot refuses to plot the data, saying that "y-values are undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```
set output "snowData.png"
set title  "Data from Weather Station Yard"
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H"
set xrange [00:24]
set xtics  
set xlabel "Time(hrs)"
set ylabel "Water Content(inches)" tc lt 1      
set y2label "Temperature Deg F" tc lt 2
set grid
#set yrange  [0:2]
#set y2range [-20:80]
#set autoscale y2
set ytics 1 nomirror tc lt 1 
set y2tics 10 nomirror tc lt 2      #MUST set y2tics to view y2label

plot "logSnow.dat" using 1:2 title "Water Content(inches)" with linespoints linetype 1,
\"logSnow.dat" using 1:3 title "Temperature" with linespoints linetype 2    

Here is my data:
2019:02:20:10:55 -0.01,70.14,3.90
2019:02:20:11:26 -0.01,70.59,3.90
2019:02:20:11:57 -0.01,70.36,3.90
```

Comment: I can't get the data to list in columns. 00:02, -0.01, 67.21, 4.01 is the first record.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I get my data to plot? All I get is the graph axes with no data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two issues:

1. your data is comma separated. So, you are missing a line

   `set datafile separator ","`
2. the xrange expects a time string in the format `"%H:%M"`

   `set xrange ["00:00":"24:00"]`

with this, it should work.

The following code gives the graph below (gnuplot 5.2.5):

```
### plotting time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2019:02:20:10:55,-0.01,70.14,3.90
2019:02:20:11:26,-0.01,70.59,3.90
2019:02:20:11:57,-0.01,70.36,3.90
EOD

set datafile separator ","
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M"
set format x "%H"
set xrange ["2019:02:20:00:00":"2019:02:20:24:00"]

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp lt 1 ti "Water Content(inches)" ,\
     $Data u 1:3 w lp lt 2 ti "Temperature"
### end of code
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out error in xrange format. I added the datafile separator "," command earlier but new versions of gnuplot do not need this cmd. Apparently gnuplot expects space between time info. and data. Anyway, still doesn't plot the data points.

Comment: did you change the data? Your `set timefmt "%H:%M"` doesn't match your time data `2019:02:20:10:55`. For this, the format should probably be `"%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M"`.

Comment: Wow! You obviously found the problem. I'm anxious to try your suggestion.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!